# Docker for windows Vs Docker inside Windows Ubuntu App?

Tags: windows, docker, ubuntu, windows-10

I am trying to know the best way to run Docker in Win 10 machines that dosn't have too many resources.

I am runing Docker using the docker for windows and things run quite good but I wonder if it will be better specialy about symlinks issues and resources hunger if i run Docker inside the new Ubuntu on Windows. https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

When you try to install Docker in Ubuntu for Win a message shows advising to use Docker for Windows instead.

Any thoughts out there ?

Comment: Ubuntu in Windows is based on WSL and that is available in two flavours: One is a mapping approach of native syscalls to Windows kernel, the other one is really running a virtualized Linux kernel in some special VM in the background. So make sure which WSL you are using currently, the warning you get MIGHT be specific for the first one only. That had somewhat bad performance in some use cases. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: Of interest: [Is there a pictorial diagram of how WSL 2, Docker, Docker-desktop … are related?](https://forums.docker.com/t/is-there-a-pictorial-diagram-of-how-wsl-2-docker-docker-desktop-are-related/100071)